# How to fix "Error: Unable to create renderer for layer: undefined"?

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I am trying to add a layer to my map using openlayers 5 (loaded through npm package ol@5.3.3) and I get this error message in the browser console.
Has anyone come across this error and managed to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Answering my own question: I redefined `type` property of the layer with `Object.defineProperties(layer, { type: { ... } } );` and Openlayers did not like it since it makes use of the same property name.